# Can aberrometric contact lens correct night halo after a PRK?

Tags: eye, ophthalmology

The PRK myopia operation has corrected a strong myopic defect (9 degree) in an optical zone of 6mm of diameter. But the pupil is larger than this treated zone on the cornea. 
This means that the contact lens should correct the direction of light **only** outside an area with a diameter of 6 mm.

Can aberrometric contact lens correct night halos?

[image]

http://www.lasik-center.com/simulator/freevissimulator_result.html?dioptrien=4&pupille=f&x=85&y=9

Comment: No answers? :( .

Comment: If you've had PRK or LASIK you won't be able to wear a soft contact lens successfully, because the cornea no longer has a compatible shape to the soft lens, and it will deform to the cornea, and not perform as prescribed.  However, I have heard of folks who have had PRK or LASIK requiring additional correction, and being prescribed a hard contact lens.  It would be a custom rigid gas permeable lens with a reverse geometry design that may be able to help you.

Comment: @user12711: sorry for the direct question but are you sure? The amount of cornea ablated was less than 0,3 mm on an eye curvature which is of one centimeter. I mean.. does it really matter?

Comment: Actually I did PRK some years ago but I had no problem in wearing contact lens again.. ps: thanks very much sor the suggestion of rigid lens

Comment: In general, if you have LASIK or PRK then it causes an "irregular cornea" and interferes with the fitting of a soft contact lens.  A "reverse geometry" lens design in a rigid lens can be used to correct an irregular cornea that is not suitable for fitting with a soft lens.  If you want to be certain, you need to ask your Eye Doctor.  You must have had a minor PRK, like less than 2 diopters of correction?

Comment: For others: if you're a young adult considering LASIK etc., ask them Before the surgery because you might need a "touchup" later in life.   Also, be advised that there are high performance soft contacts made of Silicon-Hydrogel that (depending on the individual) can be left in the eye up to one month at a time.  However, I failed to follow proper guidelines and would leave them in my eyes several months at a time, and just forget about them.  Fortunately I never had an ill aftereffect.  They also make Rigid contacts for up to 30 days, for those with perfectly healthy corneas.